# Flipping UICollectionViewCell over causes other cells to flip

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using the following animation to flip a UICollectionViewCell over to reveal a confirmation view "on the back" of the cell:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:cell.cellContentWrap
                    toView:cell.confirmationView
                  duration:1.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
 }
 ];
```

When I am done, I notice that every 8 cells in the collection view has also has the confirmation view showing. Mind blown. Thoughts on why this is occurring? I've tried calling reloadData on the collection view, and reloadingItemsAtIndexPaths for that cell... What am I missing about UICollectionViews/UICollectionViewCells and/or their corresponding animations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked very much with collection views, but they use the same cell reuse design as table views.

When a collection cell scrolls off-screen, it gets put in a reuse queue for later. Then, when the system needs a new collection view cell, it pulls one out of the reuse queue if one is available and uses it instead of creating a new one.

If you've mucked around with your cell's view hierarchy, those changes will persist. Every time that cell is the cell that's pulled off the reuse queue, it will have it's views switched around.

In your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, after you call 
`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, you should force it's view hierarchy back to the default state (switching the subviews around, so the cell's cellContentWrap view is shown instead of it's confirmationView, but without animation).

Comment: Add that he has to use `prepareForReuse` to reset his cell :-)

Comment: He doesn't **HAVE** to use prepareForReuse. I often don't, and instead reconfigure my cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath (or cellForItemAtIndexPath in this case)

Comment: If you have a complex cell and you want to unload controller, it's the way to go, plus all cell code is in cell itself. Cleaner code. Better reusability.